# Increasing WiFi adapter's Tx-power risks

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

Will my WiFi adapter be damaged if I increase the Tx-power too much?

Comment: How would you change the TX power of the adapter?

Comment: I googled and there are lots of way to do it.

Comment: If you share how you would do it, people might be able to respond to your question.

Comment: Probably will use this instruction [link](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-your-wi-fi-cards-tx-power-higher-than-30-dbm-0149606/)

Comment: If you're just changing a locale setting on the adapter, that shouldn't damage the adapter.  Depending on where you live, however, if that causes interference for anyone else, you might be subject to having your equipment confiscated.

Comment: I understand the legal issues, of course. My query is about the power not the locale. Will changing the transmission power damage my adapter? What if I increase it to over 35dbm. Let's assume I live in a place where there is no restriction set for the TX power.

Comment: If you're just using a setting that someone in another country can use without damaging the adapter, why would you expect it to damage yours?

Comment: It is possible to bypass the country limit. That is the point. If I say set it to 35dbm will my adapter die?

Comment: Keep in mind: Increasing the TX power will degrade the signal quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is heat ... I've increased the power on a wireless base station, and immediately noticed the higher heat output of the base station.  It failed later that hot summer.  Some people put heatsinks on when doing the same thing.
Similar things can happen to your wireless adapter.  We don't know what model adapter you're using, whether it's installed inside a laptop, what model laptop, etc.  Laptops are designed to get heat away from the CPU and other hottest components, but probably your wireless card's standard heat output wasn't enough to warrant a cooling solution.
In short - it's possible to burn out your wireless adapter and possibly other components if they get too warm.